# Ccontent entity reference field storing entity ID in form, not value from view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am trying to use an entity reference field in my content type that uses a views filter to limit the fields in the entity and place them in a select list in a new content form. This works fine. However when I publish the form, it only saves the entity id - not the values that the view returned to the select box. I need to do this in the Drupal UI to include it in a features override.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? The only thing I have come up with is the `Entity Reference View Widget` module, but the maintainer has placed a note on the module page stating that it should not be used. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [**entityreference_dynamicselect_widget module**](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_dynamicselect_widget). But in any case the 2562 sites that are currently using the *Entity Reference View Widget* module add much value to this module.

Comment: Hi Thank you for responding. I did not receive any notification of your response. I just happened to go back and check it. I originally tried the Entity Reference View Widget module and the maintainer had posted a note saying that it should not be used. I tried it anyway and was unable to determine how it would accomplish what I need. I am reading up on the one you suggested now and will probably try it. I have been able to force a display of the value using Display Suite Code Field, however, this is a round about way of doing things. Hollye

Answer (score 0):

is there any solution to get any specific field other than the entity Id's .
The form is always populated with either the title or the entire content (based on the settings provided) but never with the specific table column that i want.

thanks.